# OpenAI Is throwing timeout errors

Tags: openai-api

I'm using an Azure OpenAI gpt-35-turbo deployment. I'm accessing it using API request.
After a few seconds I get timeout errors:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxx.openai.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //openai/deployments/gpt-35-turbo/chat/completions?api-version=2023-03-15-preview (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd50e29f550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

Looks like there isn't a way to increase timeout threshold, so I'm not sure what else can be done